# how to put spaces after numbers in a string js

Tags: javascript, string, spaces

I have a task to return number of a letter in alphabet instead of given letters. So, if I have the word 'Wow!' - I should return '23 15 23'.

the problem is I can't put spaces between numbers and have result '231523'.

When I try to put it I have an error if it's only a single letter - for 'a' I have '1 ' instead of '1'. 
How can I put it?

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Comment: you have to provide code without we cannot change in output

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow it would be worth reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a feel for the information we need to answer a question well. As already commented the code, and the error message is a good place to start.

Comment: you would need to replace every letter with the corresponding numbers, if there are more letters you should add an space. also provide an minimal code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

1. Split the string.
2. Get the char code and do required operations
3. Join the array with spaces.

```js
var str = "Wow";
var opt = str.split("").map(function(el){ return el.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96;}).join(" ");
alert(opt);
```